# Integer pairs in Cocos2d for iPhone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, integer

Currently I'm storing integer grid coordinates in `CGPoints` using the `ccp` macro. Is there anything like `ccpi` in Cocos2d for iPhone that stores a pair of integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, CGPoint is a struct that contains 2 floats. So, if you want to store a pair of integers instead, one way would be to roll your own struct with integers.

```
struct CGIntegerPoint {
   NSInteger x;
   NSInteger y;
};

CG_INLINE CGIntegerPoint
CGIntegerPointMake(NSInteger x, NSInteger y)
{
  CGIntegerPoint p; p.x = x; p.y = y; return p;
}
```

With that, you could then define your own "*ccpi*" macro if you wish:

```
#define ccpi(__X__,__Y__) CGIntegerPointMake(__X__,__Y__)
```